# V-I curve for Stepper Motor

Tags: stepper-motor, graph

I am new to stepper and want to know how velocity-current graphs are plotted for stepper motor. Is the speed graph plotted against the overall current drawn by the motor or it's single winding current?
Please suggest me for this little confusion.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A velocity-current-Graph does not seem to make a lot of sense to me. It is possible to create a graph like that, if the input voltage is fixed, but in power applications, steppers are usually used in constant current configuration. Without seeing the datasheet, I can not be sure (I don't know whether I can with seeing the datasheet), but I typically raw motor datasheets list per-winding currents, while datasheets for drivers might list input current (total) or output current (per winding).

Comment: Thanks Michael, actually i want to plot graphs as in this [link](http://www.solarheatengines.com/2011/01/28/generating-power-with-a-stepper-motor/) but confused they are plotting total current or just single winding current.

Comment: Thanks for the link. In that report about using a stepper motor as generator, they plotted the load current, so it's the average total current drawn from the windings.